# Quiz Validiating Answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok, so I have a diagnosis quiz created with questions for 4 categories (each category has 5 questions). I'm trying to no avail to figure out how I can add up the scores and depending how how they scored on each category tell the user that category they belong to.

All the questions have the same 4 options: never, occasionally, often, always. However the weighting for each of the possible answers is different. Never has a value of 0, occasionally has a value of 1, often a value of 2 and always a value of 3.

So as an example lets say the first 5 questions belonged to one category (category A) and the player answered Never, often, often, always and never. Their score for that category would be 7, and if this was the highest category then show it to the player.

Anyone know how I would go about doing this?

My thinking is that I need to have some sort of increment system that adds the values to  4 variables that act as the categories? I am not really sure, so I suppose that's why I'm posting on here.

```html
<!-- A GAME OF CARDS HOME SCREEN -->
<div id="home" class="content">
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <p><font size="32"> A Game of Cards</font>
  </p>
  <a class="btnStart" href="#">
    <img src="cards.jpg" />
  </a>
  <button id="buttonone" class="myButton" type="button">Start Quiz</button>
</div>
<!-- END OF HOME SCREEN -->


<!-- START OF AVATAR DIV -->
<div id="Avatar" class="panel">
  <p><font size="28">Please choose an Avatar</font>
  </p>
  <div class="content">

    <img id="Boy" src="Boydone.png" class="Avatars" onclick="changeImgToBoy(); stay();" />
    <img id="Girl" src="Girldone.png" class="Avatars" onclick="changeImgToGirl(); stay2();" />
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" align="center" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF AVATAR DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 1 DIV -->
<div id="Question1" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img1" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you find little interest or pleasure in doing things?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q1">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q1">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q1">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q1">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 1 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 2 DIV -->
<div id="Question2" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img2" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have you ever felt you should Cut down on your drinking?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q2">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q2">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q2">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q2">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 2 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 3 DIV -->

<div id="Question3" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img3" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you constantly compare yourself to others?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q3">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q3">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q3">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q3">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 3 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 4 DIV -->
<div id="Question4" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img4" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />If you do well at something, do you tend to put it down to luck, rather than feel pleased with yourself?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q4">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q4">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q4">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q4">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 4 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 5 DIV -->
<div id="Question5" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img5" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you sometimes think what it would be like if you were not around?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q5">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q5">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q5">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q5">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 5 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 6 DIV -->
<div id="Question6" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img6" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you feel that other people tend to dislike you?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q6">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q6">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q6">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q6">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 6 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 7 DIV -->

<div id="Question7" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img7" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have people annoyed you by criticizing your drinking?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q7">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q7">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q7">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q7">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 7 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 8 DIV -->
<div id="Question8" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img8" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Are you having trouble falling or staying asleep, or sleeping too much?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q8">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q8">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q8">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q8">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 8 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 9 DIV -->
<div id="Question9" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img9" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have you ever injured yourself or anyone as a result of alcohol consumption?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q9">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q9">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q9">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q9">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 9 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 10 DIV -->
<div id="Question10" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img10" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you feel that your opinion doesn't matter to other people?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q10">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q10">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q10">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q10">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 10 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 11 DIV -->
<div id="Question11" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img11" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have you ever cut or done damage to your skin on purpose?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q11">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q11">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q11">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q11">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 11 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 12 DIV -->
<div id="Question12" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img12" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you have any interest in the outside world?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q12">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q12">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q12">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q12">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 12 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 13 DIV -->
<div id="Question13" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img13" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Are you shy?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q13">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q13">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q13">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q13">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 13 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 14 DIV -->
<div id="Question14" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img14" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you ever get a feeling of hopelessness?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q14">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q14">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q14">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q14">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 14 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 15 DIV -->
<div id="Question15" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img15" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have you ever had a drink first thing in the morning to steady your nerves or to get rid of a hangover?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q15">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q15">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q15">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q15">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 15 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 16 DIV -->
<div id="Question16" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img16" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you find yourself feeling tired or having little energy?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q16">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q16">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q16">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q16">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 16 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 17 DIV -->
<div id="Question17" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img17" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have you found yourself feeling down, upset, or hopeless for no reason?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q17">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q17">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q17">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q17">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 17 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 18 DIV -->
<div id="Question18" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img18" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have you ever felt bad or Guilty about your drinking?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q18">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q18">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q18">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q18">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 18 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 19 DIV -->
<div id="Question19" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img19" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Do you sometimes feel like no one cares about you?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q19">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q19">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q19">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q19">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 19 DIV -->

<!-- START OF QUESTION 20 DIV -->
<div id="Question20" class="panel">
  <div class="question">
    <img id="img20" src="Girldone.png" alt="girlAvatar" />Have you had a poor appetite or overeating?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="answers">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="a" type="radio" name="Q20">Never</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="b" type="radio" name="Q20">Occasionally</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="c" type="radio" name="Q20">Often</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input data-key="d" type="radio" name="Q20">Always</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="buttontwo" class="myButton" type="button">Finish</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF QUESTION 20 DIV -->
```

Comment: tl;dr version please.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Please save yourself the trouble and generate the questions in JavaScript. :-/

Comment: What do you mean by that Polywhirl?

Comment: You need to set value for each radiobutton element and then on client or server side you need to add logic that will process values from each radiobutton. Depending on names you can group results and then show it to visitor (and scroll to whatever position you need)